# Dynamically filter html table data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a html table with data coming from mysql database.

I would like to filter the table data dynamically with different filters applied. Also I can choose which filters to be removed once it is applied. Sorry for bad explanation. I can explain with an example.

I have the following online shopping website
[flipkart_mobiles](http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles?otracker=nmenu_sub_electronics_0_Mobiles)

On the left have many filters like brand of mobile, price range, OS type and so on.

When I select brand of mobile say Motorola and price range of Rs10,000 - Rs 18,000. We get two filters activated and shows "Shows 13 results in" ( please check the picture attached for reference )
[image: dynamic filtering example]
now we can remove the filters existing by pressing close button beside the filter or add more filters on the existing filtered data.

I would like to implement something like this in my html table. However I do not know how is this named ( hence named it dynamic filtering ) or how to implement it.

Please guide me how its implemented. Is it done using javascript or php or something else. Also what this technique is called.

I am a newbie to front end development and I work alone hence I dont know how to search for it. Please suggest me some tutorials on how to implement it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually several ways to perform what you want to do :

- You could use ajax requests to filter what you want (since you put [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), I suggest you to look at the [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation).

  It is an easy way to do this. But it won't be very efficient since you'll have to perform a request to the server each time the user choose an option (which can be long if you have a lot of data).
- You could also fetch all the data first, when arriving to this page (using pure PHP would be even easier than `ajax`), and store all of this in an [JS object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

  I get it might be slow. But it will only be at the page loading. Not at every request as the `ajax` way does.

  Then in your `option click` event, you can refresh your current displayed table with new data according to both the object you created and the option you selected. E.g :

  ```
  // This var is created using PHP for example
  var phones = [
      {"name" : "Moto X Play (16GB)", "brand" : "Motorola", "price" : 15499}, 
      {"name" : "Moto X Play (32GB)", "brand" : "Motorola", "price" : 17499},
      /* And a lot of other phones of course */
  ];

  // Then, if you chose a specific brand, you can display only phones with this brand by using phones["brand"] values.
  ```

---

### Edit :

It all depends what you want to do in your project :

- If you just want to train yourself on a personal project, or if you are doing this for a small company (no more than a few thousands rows in database, and a few thousands users), you'd rather using the pure PHP way.
- If you plan to be the most successful entrepreneur of the year and expect your project to be used worldwide by hundreds of thousands of users, you'd better use the `ajax` way.

In both case, you should use [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), which is a really good JS framework to perform on huge amount of data.

Comment: Please explain me , what will happen , if there are 20k + or 30k + records inside database and all of them are requested together on page load with at same time a lot users loading the site together ? . and talking about angular , angular also requests your server's api for the data .

Comment: @ArshSingh **You'd better have a good server !** Jokes beside, it all depends on the project OP wants to do. If it is aimed for selling products, you won't ever have more than a few thousands. In this case, it will be more efficient to fetch them all.

Comment: it's always better to be prepared for huge load for the server , let say few thousands products and then the user requests increases (page load) from 1k to 10k , it's same , it will crash or make the server slow.

Comment: @ all -- the tables I am using is just text data ( no images involved ) and they have around 5k - 10k rows and about 10 - 15 columns.  Please suggest the best method among the suggested ones

Comment: @sravankumar  , it's alot. please load on request. Please google about the problems related to the loading all of records like 10k records together , you will find oracle's (mysql creator) 's response it self about filter on request.

Comment: @sravankumar Edited to suit your question. I guess with what you told, you'd better use the `ajax` way, but it all depends on how many users you have (number of request you will have at once)/

Comment: @tektiv: Thank you for your explanation